# Confused about imports and evals -- Python

Tags: python

Say we have two scripts, script1 and script2.

script1 is defined as:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class bar(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

def test(givenString):
    return eval(givenString)
```

and script2 is defined as:

```
from .script1 import test

x = "Foo('me')"
print test(x)
```

script2's print statement for `test(x)` successfully tells me that I have a `Foo` object, but that doesn't make sense to me because I only imported `test` from script1, not `Foo`. I looked at the `eval` documentation but that didn't clear up much for me. How is it possible that a `Foo` object is created even when I never imported the class `Foo`?

Comment: I wonder if you have a C background and you expect `import` to act like an include statement and `from mymodule import myfunction` to act like some sort of conditional include.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I did a little bit of C, but not enough to say I have a C background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`eval()` uses the globals of the module it is executed in. `test` 'lives' in the `script1` global namespace, so any expression executed by `eval()` uses the same namespace as that function and thus can resolve `Foo`, `bar` and `test`.

Importing a function does not alter its namespace; the globals for `test` don't change merely by being called from `script2`. If it did, any imports in `script1` would *also* need to be imported into `script2`, for each and every function you ever wanted to use. That would be incredibly impractical.

You can even see the globals for functions you import; `print test.func_globals` will show you the exact namespace of `script1`.

Comment: Then presumably `exec` acts similarly?

Comment: Martijn Pieters So then each function defined in the same script contains the same `func_globals dict`? Isn't that kind of redundant?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian: they are all *references* to the same object. You can reach the same object by looking at `vars(sys.modules['script1'])`.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian: The reference is the means by which global names are looked up in functions. `import os`, `def foo(path): return os.listdir(path)` looks up `os` as a global in `foo.func_globals` when you call it.

Comment: Martijn Pieters, one last question, when we say references, in CPython, that really means pointers?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian: CPython implements references as pointers to objects in the heap, yes, with reference counting.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian: In CPython, they're implemented as pointers, but they don't have to be. They could be pointers to pointers, or Java references (which would themselves probably be implemented as pointers), or even mailing addresses in China where physical scratch paper representing the objects is stored.